# How do i pass this pointSetKeepsTrackOfPoints() test? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, performance

This is the test i can not seem to pass and i am not sure what should i do now:

```
 @Test
public void pointSetKeepsTrackOfPoints() {
    PointSet set = new PointSet();

    set.add(new Point(1, 1));
    set.add(new Point(2, 1));
    set.add(new Point(1, 2));

    assertThat(set.size(), is(3));

    set.add(new Point(2, 1));

    assertThat(set.size(), is(3));

    assertTrue(set.contains(new Point(1, 1)));
    assertTrue(set.contains(new Point(1, 2)));
    assertFalse(set.contains(new Point(1, 3)));

    assertThat(set.toString(), is("(1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 2)"));
}
```

And this is my code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PointSet {

    private Point[] points;
    private int size;

    public PointSet(int capacity) {
        points = new Point[capacity];
        size = 0;
    }

    public PointSet() {
        this(10);
    }

    public void add(Point point) {
        if (size == points.length) {
            Point[] newPoints = new Point[points.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                newPoints[i] = points[i];
            }
            points = newPoints;
        }
        points[size] = point;
        size++;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean contains(Point point) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (points[i].equals(point)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public PointSet subtract(PointSet other) {
        PointSet result = new PointSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!other.contains(points[i])) {
                result.add(points[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public PointSet intersect(PointSet other) {
        PointSet result = new PointSet();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (other.contains(points[i])) {
                result.add(points[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sb.append(points[i]);
            if (i < size - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof PointSet) {
            PointSet other = (PointSet) obj;
            if (size != other.size) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (!other.contains(points[i])) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help me...
There are no duplicates in the set, ie two points with the same coordinates.
If you add a point that already contains, the number does not change. The points in between should be kept in an array.

Comment: Nowhere do you check for existing Points in the set in your `add` method. What is the definition of `Point`? Does it override `equals` and `hashCode`? Why do you use a fixed-size array to keep track of the points and not a `Set` (e.g. `HashSet`)? By using existing data structures your methods become simple one-liners delegating to existing (and working) implementations.

Comment: I have to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must use arrays and not a data structure which better fits your need (i.e. `Set`), then you have to make sure that "equal" Point instances cannot be added to your `PointSet` instance. Before adding a new item, check that none of the existing items are equal to the new item. You can do it with a simple loop. The equality comparison can either be implemented in the `Point` class or manually checked inside the loop, if `Point`s expose everything that is required to check for equality.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the advice. I will make sure to check for equality before adding any new items to my PointSet instance.